# How to use EqualTo constraint in validation component when data is passed as array in Symfony?

Tags: symfony

Symfony provides way to validate array as per https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/raw_values.html and using it I want to use EqualTo constraint (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/EqualTo.html) which is not working with password and confirm password case. Please see code below:

```
$this->constraint = new Assert\Collection([
        // the keys correspond to the keys in the input array
        'fields' => [
            'password' =>
                [
                    new Assert\NotBlank(['message' => 'Please enter password.']),
                    new Assert\Length(['min' => 5, 'minMessage' => 'Please enter password of 5 characters at least.']),
                ]
            ,
            'confirm_password' =>
                [
                    new Assert\NotBlank(['message' => 'Please enter confirm password.']),
                    new Assert\EqualTo(['propertyPath' => 'password']),
                ]
            ,
        ],
        'allowMissingFields' => false,
        'missingFieldsMessage' => 'Please enter value.',
    ]);
```

Now, calling it:

```
$this->validator = Validation::createValidator();
$this->validator->validate($input, $this->constraint, $groups);
```

Above doesn't work.

The idea is to validate request's data first before preparing the entity and then persist the entity duly. Also, I want to separate the validation mechanism from vary entity.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of EqualsTo use Callback constraint

```
        $this->constraint = new Assert\Collection([
        // the keys correspond to the keys in the input array
        'fields' => [
            'password' =>
                [
                    new Assert\NotBlank(['message' => 'Please enter password.']),
                    new Assert\Length(['min' => 5, 'minMessage' => 'Please enter password of 5 characters at least.']),
                ]
            ,
            'confirm_password' =>
                [
                    new Assert\NotBlank(['message' => 'Please enter confirm password.']),
                    new Assert\Callback(['callback' => function ($value, ExecutionContext $ec) {
                        if ($ec->getRoot()['password'] !== $value) {
                            $ec->addViolation("Passwords do not match");
                        }
                    }])
                ]
            ,
        ],
        'allowMissingFields' => false,
        'missingFieldsMessage' => 'Please enter value.',
    ]);
```

Comment: I posted my message for you and probable solution above. Text was too long for comment hence I need to post it likewise. Please refer, thanks.